# Find Anchor Tag from Listview InsertItemTemplate to Codebehind ItemData bound

Tags: asp.net

I want to set anchor tag visible false/True and want to set value to it ,in Code Behind ListView_ItemDataBound. Anchor tag is inside Listview Insert ItemTemplate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use linkbutton instead of anchor tag...

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        LinkButton linkButton = e.item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
        if (linkButton != null)
            linkButton.Visible = false;
    }
```

or use this code

```
HtmlGenericControl anchor = e.item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as HtmlGenericControl;
anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "page.htm");
anchor.InnerText = "TabX";
anchor. Visible = false;
```

Comment: Linkbutton makes postback which refreshes images of my listview that's y I don't want to use linkbutton. I am using Child ListView Inside Parent Listview. I want to get either anchor tag id on code behind or anchor tag hold the value inside Insert item template in listview.

Comment: this code "   HtmlGenericControl anchor = e.item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as HtmlGenericControl;
anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "page.htm");
anchor.InnerText = "TabX";
anchor. Visible = false;  " for html anchor tag...